# How do I populate an array inside of an object with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object that has an array with it. Something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ jobs: [] });
```

Now I am fetching data from an API & I need to add that fetched information to the jobs array. How do I do that? When I do this: `setData(newData)` it is not going into that jobs array.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the result in an object and use then jobs key.

setData({ jobs: newData })

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck so long with this & the answer is easy. Life saver lol